# Make an custom view and extends it from other activities

Tags: android, view, android-custom-view

i have a game which have a recycle process for each level , but it will be harder by the time,
can i make a view for common feature and extend it by each level activity??

any one have a solution ? or another idea ? ( i need each level in a separated activity )

that's what i made ...

```
public class Prev extends Activity{
private Bitmap image1;
private Bitmap image2;
private Bitmap image3;
private Bitmap image4;

private final int IMAGE_1_X = 50;
private final int IMAGE_2_X = 450;
private final int IMAGE_3_X = 50;
private final int IMAGE_4_X = 450;

private final int IMAGE_1_Y = 50;
private final int IMAGE_2_Y = 50;
private final int IMAGE_3_Y = 300;
private final int IMAGE_4_Y = 300;


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Preview p = new Preview(this);
        setContentView(p);
}
public void setImages(Bitmap image1, Bitmap image2, Bitmap image3, Bitmap image4)
{
    this.image1 = image1;
    this.image2 = image2;
    this.image3 = image3;
    this.image4 = image4;
}
public void setRawsNames(String sound_1, String sound_2, String sound_3, String sound_4)
{
    this.sound_1 = sound_1;
    this.sound_2 = sound_2;
    this.sound_3 = sound_3;
    this.sound_4 = sound_4;
}
 public class Preview extends SurfaceView{

public Preview(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.drawBitmap(image1, IMAGE_1_X, IMAGE_1_Y,null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(image2, IMAGE_2_X, IMAGE_2_Y,null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(image3, IMAGE_3_X, IMAGE_3_Y,null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(image4, IMAGE_4_X, IMAGE_4_Y,null);
}
}
```

}

here i will extend the upper class

```
public class MainActivity extends Prev {
private Bitmap image1;
private Bitmap image2;
private Bitmap image3;
private Bitmap image4;

public MainActivity() 
{  
    preperImages();
    setImages(image1, image2, image3, image4);
}
private void preperImages()
{
    image1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.one);
    image2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.two);
    image3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.three);
    image4 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.four);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you exactly want to achieve. From what I understand, you want to reuse a view. For this, you can use [include](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) tag in your layout.